# parse spinner's position to new activity

Tags: android, android-intent, position, spinner

I am trying to parse the selected position of a spinner from one activity to another and Toast it in order to see if it works. So, I saved and send the position from the first activity with :

```
int spinnerItem = mSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
intent.putExtra("position", spinnerItem);
```

Then, I went to the second activity, I tried to call it and then Toast it, but when I run the programm, it stop!!

```
Integer pos=getIntent().getIntExtra("position",0);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),pos,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Do you have any idea why it doesn't work?? I am sure is something small, but I cannot see it now.. Thank you!!

Comment: by `parse` you mean `pass`?

Comment: @ni gi see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for your problem.
Simply add the ""+ before the pos because Toast.makeText shows String value and you are showing the integer so make it string.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+pos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Welcome bro :) You can also do this using String.valueOf(pos) as below posted by Abdul Waheed the problem is in his post the of() which is not small but the captial Of(). This is just another way to convert integer to String.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper yes you are right it was just typo :) thanks to pointing out that

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert integer value that is your position you may use below step to do so

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueof(pos),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

hope that helps you

Comment: Sorry dear it was just type it is String.valueOf(). Of with capital O :)